# How to insert data into the excel using LINQ in Selenium C#?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, c#

For a login check case-> how to insert data into the Excel sheet after each login is checked whether the login credentials are valid or not using LINQ in Selenium C#.

Answer (score 1):

LINQ is not something that can insert data to excel. So the answer for your question is "you can't do that with only LINQ"